# Book with a fire hydrant with a tongue impaling a bird on the cover

Tags: story-identification

A book I read in the late nineties to early 2000s.  A boy and a girl travel to another dimension (?) with a creature that resembled a miniature star.  The villain was a humanoid guy that may have been a demon, I remember him being described as very tall.  He often rode a horse.

Most distinctively, the cover featured a cityscape with a fire hydrant on a street corner with a tongue reaching out of its spout and snaking up into the sky and impaling a bird in flight overhead.  I believe the protagonists were also on the cover.

Comment: Was this a novel or an anthology of stories?

Comment: Definitely a novel.  Pretty sure it was standalone.  It may have sequels but wasn't part of a series.

Comment: If Sevvak is right (and I think they are), it is part of a series, albeit one that has books that can be read pretty independently.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe this is [So You Want to Be a Wizard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/So_You_Want_to_Be_a_Wizard) by Diane Duane. The 'bird-eating fire hydrant' you've described is something that happens in the book.

You can see the cover below. The hydrant is in the bottom left corner.

[image]

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing that info into your answer.

Comment: Seconded that this is the right answer.